# I would like to make riddles bulletin board with WordPress

Tags: wordpress, messageboard

I would like to create **an Internet forum (message board) in WordPress where people can post riddles** and I would appreciate your advice.

Hello to all respondents and viewers (Sorry about my bad English. I am not a native English speaker).
As mentioned above, I would like to create a riddle an internet forum using WordPress, but I don’t have enough knowledge for programming, so I have tried several plugins. However, I am having trouble finding a plugin that meets the following criteria. I would be very grateful if you could provide me with a compatible plugin or programming code.

[Required features]

1. An account must be created to post riddles and enter comments (Google account is OK).
2. When you post riddles, the answer to the riddle must be written in a separate field from the riddle text box. After posting, other viewers can see the answer by clicking on "Answer".
3. Visitors can rate the difficulty and fun of riddles (e.g., on a scale of 1 to 10). No account is required just to rate the riddles.
4. The rating level (average of ratings) from other people is automatically calculated and displayed for each posted riddle (people can see the difficulty level of the riddles).
5. The account of users will accumulate riddles that he/she has posted in the past. People can see their previous riddles by checking their accounts.

Thank you in advance for your cooperation.

It would be appreciated if you could provide me some advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you can do this type of application your need a web developer to build this.But if you want you can use the following steps.

1. the easiest way to achieve this is you can use post section as riddles or you can use plugin to create costume post for riddles.
2. to allow user/visitor to login in your website you can simply change the setting of wordpress. you can google it according to your wordpress version.
3. your can use rating plugin to implement this 3rd feature i recommend `Site Reviews` plugin for this.
4. you can achieve this without any programming knowledge.
5. It can be in your profile dashboard when you allow users to login.